# RCTEventEmitter causing issues while making iOS archive

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

We are trying to make a build of React Native app in iOS and everything goes fine when we run the app on the iOS device whether it is in debug mode or release mode.

But for uploading when we try to make the archive of the app in Xcode then it throws an peculiar error that : **Duplicate interface definition for class 'RCTEventEmitter'**

We are really struck solving this, if someone could please help us.
React Native version is 0.59.10

https://share.getcloudapp.com/7KuyKmAn This is the error.

Any help regarding this is really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with delete derivedData of XCode?

Comment: @BrijeshShiroya Already, cleaned, deleted still no luck, yet I was able to make a build with some hack but still trying to find a permanent solution

Comment: I think there are some conflicts between schemas. Are you using multiple schemas?

Comment: Multiple schemas, as in?

Comment: Like production, staging

Comment: Nope only one.. I can run the build in either debug or release when I run that in the device. but while archiving it is giving that error.

Comment: Select editSchema>Select archieve option from left panel> and check build configuation, which one is selected?

Comment: Release is selected

Comment: @BrijeshShiroya I've updated the screenshot

Comment: Try with delete  ios/build directory and cmd+B, cmd +R

Comment: Tried all the above already, no luck!